# Developer tools crashing IE9

Tags: debugging, internet-explorer-9, ie-developer-tools

I have a problem on a website with IE9 which requires me to open the developer tools in that browser. That is when my real problem occurs as IE9 simply crashes and reports the following error:

```
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   APPCRASH
  Application Name: iexplore.exe
  Application Version:  9.0.8112.16447
  Application Timestamp:    4fca012b
  Fault Module Name:    KERNELBASE.dll
  Fault Module Version: 6.1.7601.17651
  Fault Module Timestamp:   4e21213c
  Exception Code:   e06d7363
  Exception Offset: 000000000000cacd
  OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.48
  Locale ID:    1030
  Additional Information 1: 4200
  Additional Information 2: 42004fe80739b889628da270848694a8
  Additional Information 3: 7bb7
  Additional Information 4: 7bb73118f9bbd17fcc14066196aedb9d
```

I also get the error with the following code:

```
Exception Code: c000041d
```

IE9 kindly restarts without any dev tools to help me.

Any idea what might cause this ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: best bet: reinstall IE9. next best bet: reinstall windows.

Comment: 0 of 4 questions with answers accepted... have a look if any of them deserve to be accepted.

Comment: Thank you Eric. But there is a reason why I have not accepted any answer and that is because I did not get an answer to my questions. I have on the other hand taken the time to answer peoples comments and answers to clarify why they weren't the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reset and fixing did not solve it. On the other hand, a complete uninstall-reinstall procedure using the corresponding windows update did the trick.

For anyone interested here's how: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/how-do-i-install-or-uninstall-internet-explorer-9

Thanks for the suggestion Marc!

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Reset Internet Explorer settings and check if that fixes the issue.

Run the “Fix it” from the following article:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/923737

Comment: Thank you, I tried that but the error remains.. unfortunately.